# if() condition in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, if-statement

I see somewhere in the code that if() expression has no block and it is terminated by semicolon ;
is this valid to use such in C++

```cpp
if (fcntl(clntSock_->getCopyConn(), F_SETFL,
    fcntl(clntSock_->getCopyConn(), F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK));
```

Comment: That code is nonsense. It's legal, but the `if` is pointless; the code would do exactly the same thing if the `if(` and the matching `)` were removed. Probably a remnant of an earlier version that was inartfully edited.

Comment: Or perhaps somewhere the programmer intended to return and add the error-checking.

Comment: `for` or `while` can be seen without bodies when the condition evaluation has side effects or polls for something that changes independently. Having an empty `if` body mostly makes no sense. My wild guess is that the project has _lint_ settings requiring code to inspect return values of important functions. To silence a _lint_ warning (which may or may not be appropriate, depending on context and circumstances), people use constructs like `(void)fcntl(...);` or `if(fcntl(...));`. In this case, because failing to set `O_NONBLOCK` may cause a freeze later, the return value _should_ be inspected.

Comment: @YSC The question doesn't show any basic research effort. The actual question is: _"is this valid to use such in C++"_ Every good introduction book or tutorial would explain it. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Could you please point me to such tutorial @jabaa? This is quite the dark corner of C++ we are talking here.

Comment: @YSC It's not a tutorial, but it's part of the expected research effort (RTFM): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements The syntax is `if constexpr(optional) ( init-statement (optional) condition ) statement-true`. `statement-true` is a statement. The syntax for a statement is `attr (optional) expression (optional) ;` That means that `;` is a valid statement and allowed after the if-condition. I don't know any current introduction tutorials. It's a long time since I read the last one. `;` is also mentioned as null-statement.

Comment: Then you're _technically correct_ (the best kind of correct). I yet fail to convince myself OP could have found and understood this documentation.

Comment: @YSC I like the the accepted answer. _"How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?"_ _"A lot. Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer—if the information that you need already exists, then you should be able to find it before asking.

You want to

    Search. Like mad.
    Test your code.
    Troubleshoot.
    Read blogs.
    Find books.
    Follow tutorials.

After you have reached the end of your rope with the pain of not having the answer, that's when you can go ahead and ask."_

Comment: @YSC That's the reason why so many questions about basic syntax are (IMO correctly) downvoted, but AFAIK it's only a downvote reason, not a close reason.

Comment: What are you trying to do?